# Grep Extract - Extract text value from image source

Tags: regex, burp

I am trying to pull a value from my HTML Source code and use it as a Grep Extract.

Using Burp Suite's 'Grep - Extract', how do I extract the following text value (in this case the text is hello, but it changes every time and I want to be able to extract the value of text=)?

```
<div id="CaptchaImage">
     <img src="Captcha.ashx?text=hello">
</div>
```

Define at start and end? 
Or Extract from regex group?

I can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: what have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define at start and end, start after expression `src="Captcha.ashx?text=`, end at delimiter `"`.

Alternatively, define from regex group `src="Captcha.ashx\?text=([^"]+)"`. And here's hoping I didn't forget any backslashes in there.